# Query wcf data service metadata when user downn't authenticated

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I need to allow users to browse my wcf data service metadata. In the overide of `CreateDataSource` I check if the user is authenticated. But if I request the service to get the metadata I still get an exception, the user doesn't get in if not authorized.

Is there a way that I can provide users with my the metadata without having them be authenticated?